# What is the equivalent of using python-firebase's ".get" statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, json, firebase

I wrote python code that looks like this and returns the enire JSON database.

```
from firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://name_name_name.firebaseio.com/')
result = firebase.get('/results', None)
```

I have tried to do the same thing in javascript with no success. This should be straight forward but I haven't seen any solutions.
The idea is to host this on the server. It will pass the **result** variable to an XML converter. The XML will print to either that same document or another document in the directory.

**What is the JavaScript equivalent of my Python code?**

Comment: Use XMLHttpRequest

Comment: it returns the *entire* database? What madness is this? That said, are you asking about "in the browser", "using node as server", "using node as regular scripting language on my computer" or some other use case?

Answer (score 0):

Without any real information on where your code runs, you probably want https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase, which can be used both in the client (e.g. browsers) as well as in standard OS context (offline/server/general scripting language).

for anything JavaScript, http://npmjs.com is your one stop "is there something to do X" open source shop.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I updated with better information.
Seems like there are a lot more moving parts with js compared to 3 lines of python.

Comment: Not really though: `npm` is the JavaScript equivalent to `pip`. You *could* write your own firebase accessor, but in both JS and Python, that'd be kind of silly, they already did all the work for you =)